# How to align prime ng submenu of the menu bar to right?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have side bar and the horizontal nav bar. I use prime ng(version 9.1.3) menu bar.

nav-bar-component.html

```
  <p-menubar [model]="items"></p-menubar>
```

nav-bar-component.ts

```
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit { 

  items: MenuItem[];

  constructor() {
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
      {
        label: "User",
        icon: "pi pi-fw pi-user",
        items: [
          { label: "Profile", icon: "pi pi-fw pi-user" },
          { label: "Change Password", icon: "pi pi-fw pi-cog" },
          { label: "Log Out", icon: "pi pi-fw pi-power-off" },
        ],
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

nav-bar-component.scss

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-menubar .ui-menubar-root-list {
  float: right;
}
```

The submenu of the menu bar goes out of the screen. How can we rectify the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can try with `right: 0`.

**styles.css**

```
.align-right .p-menubar-root-list>li:last-child .p-submenu-list {
  right: 0;
}
```

**.html**

```
<p-menubar [model]="items" styleClass="align-right"> <!-- declare class here -->
    <div>
        <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Search">
        <button type="button" pButton label="Logout" icon="pi pi-power-off" style="margin-left:.25em"></button>
    </div>
</p-menubar>
```

Demo [here](https://primeng-menubar-demo-sxh9sg.stackblitz.io)!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the y-axis on the html has an overflow:

use this on the global css:

```
body, html {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @DheepakS Hmm, I see, are there no changes? try adding max-width: 100vw;

Answer (score 0):

In your component css file (YOUR-COMPONENT-NAME.component.css) add the following

```
::ng-deep .p-menubar .p-submenu-list {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```